# Wix app.config Application and User Scope

Tags: wix, app-config, settings

I have a number of userSettings and applicationSettings defined in my projects app.config, the idea being a user can amend the userSettings in the UI, and we can amend the applicationSettings when necessary.

What I plan to do is have the applicationSettings alongside the exe in the APPDIR C:\Program Files{Company}{Application} folder (which means users cannot edit the file) and have the userSettings in the LocalAppDataFolder C:\Users\\AppData\Local{Company}{Application} so that the app can write to the file.

I'd appreciate some pointers on how best to achieve this with Wix, or even if this is the correct way to achieve what I'm looking to do.

I currently have:

```
  <!--main installation location-->
  <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
    <Directory Id="fooFolder" Name="foo">
      <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="Application Name" />
    </Directory>
  </Directory>

  <!-- users appdata folder-->
  <Directory Id="LocalAppDataFolder" Name="AppData">
    <Directory Id="AppRootDirectory" Name="Application Name" />
  </Directory>

</Directory>
```

```
 <Fragment>
<ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
  <Component Id="ProductComponent" Guid="{GUID}">

    <File Id="app.config.programfiles" Source="$(var.{ProjectName}.TargetDir)/{TargetName}.exe.config" />

  </Component>
</ComponentGroup>
```

```
<Fragment>

<DirectoryRef Id="ApplicationProgramsFolder">
  <Component Id="ApplicationShortcut" Guid="{GUID}">
    <Shortcut Id="ApplicationStartMenuShortcut"
         Name="My App"
       Description="My App description"
        Target="[INSTALLFOLDER]$(var.{App}.TargetFileName)"
              WorkingDirectory="INSTALLFOLDER"/>
    <RemoveFolder Id="ApplicationProgramsFolder" On="uninstall"/>
    <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\{Company}\{Application}" Name="installed" Type="integer" Value="1" KeyPath="yes"/>
  </Component>
</DirectoryRef>
```

This works fine and places the config file in the APPDIR, but I don't know what to do with the LocalAppDataFolder.

Am I approaching this the right way?

Comment: This [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/616065/Why-Where-and-How-of-NET-Configuration-Files) is a good overview; Don't miss the section on upgrading.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so this is taken care of for you the first time that any of the userSettings are amended using the Save() method of the autogenerated Settings class:

```
Settings.Default.MyProperty = "foo";
Settings.Default.Save();
```

which results in the creation a user.config file in LocalAppDataFolder\{Company}\{Application}\{ProductName_xxx}\{Version} containing only the contents of the userSettings section of the app.config.